# Classification of homogeneous Einstein manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, homogeneous-spaces

In Besse's "Einstein manifolds", p. 177, he states that, until that moment, no general classification of homogeneous Einstein manifolds was know, even in the compact case. More specifically, he poses a problem: classify the compact simply connected homogeneous manifolds $M=G/K$ which admit a $G$-invariant Einstein metric.

Does that question remain open to this day?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, the question is still open.

I suggest to read [this quite recent paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2107.06609) by Kerr and Böhm. It reviews some of the most important advances in the problem and includes several open problems.